# django if tag & ifequal tag not working correctly

Tags: python, django, django-templates

views.py:

```
def get(request):
    p = Publisher.objects.filter(name='tux')
    return render(request, 'main.html', {'items': p[0]})
```

main.html:

```
<html>    
    <body>
    {{ items }}
    <hr>
    {% if 'tux' in items %}
       <h1>this is tux</h1>
    {% else %}
       <h1>sorry!</h1>
    {% endif %}
    </body>    
</html>
```

What is printed on the webpage:

tux

---

sorry!

And what about if I want to use `{% ifequal %}` tag?
What syntax should be used? I tried this:

```
{% ifequal {{items}} 'tux' %}
```

and it turned parse error, and I also tried this:

```
{% ifequal items 'tux' %}
```

but the result was again:

tux

---

sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use it like this: `{% if 'tux' in items %}`, since items is an object.
Use `{% if 'tux' in items.name %}` instead.
The reason you get 'tux' displayed in the case of `{{items}}` is that your model returns `name` field as a unicode representation.